# Mock fs.readdir for testing

Tags: node.js, mocking, stub, sinon

I'm trying to mock the function **fs.readdir** for my tests.

At first I've tried to use **sinon** because this is a very good framework for this, but is hasn't worked.

```
stub(fs, 'readdir').yieldsTo('callback', { error: null, files: ['index.md', 'page1.md', 'page2.md'] });
```

My second attempt was to mock the function with a self-replaced function. But it also doesn't works.

```
beforeEach(function () {
  original = fs.readdir;

  fs.readdir = function (path, callback) {
    callback(null, ['/content/index.md', '/content/page1.md', '/content/page2.md']);
  };
});

afterEach(function () {
  fs.readdir = original;
});
```

Can anybody tell me why both doesn't works? Thanks!

---

Update - This also doesn't works:

```
  sandbox.stub(fs, 'readdir', function (path, callback) {
    callback(null, ['index.md', 'page1.md', 'page2.md']);
  });
```

Update2:

My last attempt to mock the **readdir** function is working, when I'm trying to call this function directly in my test. But not when I'm calling the mocked function in another module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the reason for my problem. I've created the mock in my test class tried to test my rest api with **supertest**. The problem was that the test was executed in another process as the process in that my webserver runs. I've created the express-app in my test class and the test is now green.

this is test

```
describe('When user wants to list all existing pages', function () {
    var sandbox;
    var app = express();

    beforeEach(function (done) {
      sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create(); // @deprecated — Since 5.0, use sinon.createSandbox instead

      app.get('/api/pages', pagesRoute);
      done();
    });

    afterEach(function (done) {
      sandbox.restore();
      done();
    });

    it('should return a list of the pages with their titles except the index page', function (done) {
      sandbox.stub(fs, 'readdir', function (path, callback) {
        callback(null, ['index.md', 'page1.md', 'page2.md']);
      });

      request(app).get('/api/pages')
        .expect('Content-Type', "application/json")
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }

          var pages = res.body;

          should.exists(pages);

          pages.length.should.equal(2);

          done();
        });
    });
});
```