# Mocking specific reading file error for tests in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, fs

Is it possible to mock, let's say, with the ["mock-fs"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs) library some sort of reading file errors? In particular, I want to test this case (where `code !== 'ENOENT'`):

```
fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') { 
            return done(new ReadingFileError(filePath));
        }
    }
    // ... 
});
```

I could find nothing about emulating reading errors in their docs. Maybe there are some other libraries that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `mock-fs` mocks the filesystem not the node utility. Of course in some case you can use that to test the fs utility, but I think your use case is not amongs them.

Here is an example with [sinon.sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044737/mock-fs-readdir-for-testing)

Some alternatives are:

- [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) (see example below)
- [testdouble](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js)

> Note, that I am a bit confused where the `ReadingFileError` comes from, so I guess you are trying to implement a custom error. If that is the case maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364152/how-to-create-node-js-custom-errors-and-have-the-stack-property-return-after-res) also will be helpful. In the example I replaced that with a simple `new Error('My !ENOENT error')`.

```
// readfile.js
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')

function myReadUtil (filePath, done) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
        return done(err, null)
      }
      return done(new Error('My ENOENT error'), null)
    }
    return done(null, data)
  })
}

module.exports = myReadUtil

// test.js
'use strict'

const assert = require('assert')
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')

const fsMock = {
  readFile: function (path, cb) {
    cb(new Error('My !ENOENT error'), null)
  }     
}


const myReadUtil = proxyquire('./readfile', { 'fs': fsMock })

myReadUtil('/file-throws', (err, file) => {
  assert.equal(err.message, 'My !ENOENT error')
  assert.equal(file, null)
})
```

**Edit**: Refactored the example to use node style callback instead of `throw` and `try/catch`

Comment: `ReadingFileError` is a custom class that inherits from `Error`.

Comment: That is what I assumed (see note), but I don't have it, so I can't use it in the example. It does not change anything :)